# How to make and image clickable in PHP

Tags: php, image, clickable

I would like to add a static image to my single-package.php template on my travel website.

I have included the image like this:

```
<?php

$image = "http://dev5.4loopdigital.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/servicesaccomm.jpg";  
$width = 960;
$height = 300;
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" style=width:"' . $width . 'px;height:' . $height . 'px;">';

?>
```

What must I add to make that image a clickable image that opens up that same image in a new tab/window in full size?

Thanks so much!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 1):

Currently you just have the image - what you want to do is also make the image wrapped in a link, so that when you click the image it takes you to that link's page. This can be done using the `a` HTML tag and the `href` attribute.

The following code works for me:

```
<?php

$image = "http://dev5.4loopdigital.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/servicesaccomm.jpg";  
$width = 960;
$height = 300;
echo '<a href="'.$image.'"><img src="'.$image.'" style=width:"' . $width . 'px;height:' . $height . 'px;"></a>';

?>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks so much! Kept missing that 1 little " mark that broke the whole page. THanks for the help!

Comment: Victoria, if it helped please click the green checkmark next to one of the answers so future users know which one is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the image inside an anchor

`echo '<a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="'.$image.'" style=width:"' . $width . 'px;height:' . $height . 'px;"></a>';`